# How "None" can be used with input() function in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

How `None` can be used with the `input()` function in python? The help section of the `input()` function on python IDLE shows below

```
input(prompt=None, /)
['/' marks preceding arguments as positional-only]

Read a string from the standard input. The trailing newline is stripped.
```

Comment: `prompt` is the only argument for `input` which is the message printed. `None` is simply the default which means no message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None is the default value - it just means to have an empty prompt if you call it like `input()` without any args.